# Caching images with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, leaflet

I´m building a 360 degree viewer using raster tiles (leaflet), which uses more than 85.000 images per view.
To improve viewer's performance, i´m trying to cache all images, but webbrowser always return: **net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES**

So my question is, is there any way to avoid this?

I'm using `setInterval(foo, 1000)` to do this. Something like this:

```
function restImg() {
    counter = setInterval(ld, 2000);
}

function ld() {
    if (!(nmb >= 80)) {
        for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            var idx = images[i].indexOf("-");
            var path = images[i].substr(0, idx + 1);
            nmb = parseInt(images[i].substr(idx + 1, 3));
            var rest = images[i].substr(idx + 4, images[i].length);
            nmb++;
            var img = "";
            if (nmb <= 9) {
                images[i] = path + "00" + nmb + rest;
                img = new Image();
                img.src = images[i];
            } else {
                images[i] = path + "0" + nmb + rest;
                img = new Image();
                img.src = images[i];
            }
        }
    } else {
        clearInterval(counter);
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: So you're trying to load 85,000 images on load of the page? 0.o Try lazy loading only the images which are actually visible on the screen. There are hundreds of plugins which can do this for you. This will also stop your server falling over in a heap, and saves you a *lot* of money in bandwidth

Comment: I am trying to preload all these images because viewer has a very slow or poor performance when zooming or rotating. That´s why I decided to do this. It works fine on local server, but not on remote. If I only load visible images, next images on load will delay a lot the viewer. Could you tell me the name of any of these plugins?

Comment: @victoradv, are you aware that a loaded image consumes at least width*height*4bytes of memory; independant of the format or filesize. So even if your 85000 images are only 10x10pixel in size they already consume 32MB. Don't preload all images, preload these wich are most likely to be needed next. 2nd. don't keep references to the Image-nodes. Load the images and rely on the browser-cache.

Comment: @Thomas how can I remove node-images refereces when not used from resources?

Answer (score 0):

In order to cache and lazy-load images, the state of the art is [Service Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API). This will allow you to have a finely grained control over the browser's cache without needing to rely on per-page javascript.